# How to set up Windows Live Mesh/Sync folder to sync with family/friends?

Tags: sync, windows-live-mesh

[This forum thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/LiveMesh/thread/9234de45-ea60-4f76-9cae-1bcc475312eb) suggests that it's possible to sync between friends/family, but I can't find any way to actually configure this.

I've added the other person as a "friend" on the Live website, but can't see what to do next. The Windows Live Mesh UI still doesn't offer any options that look relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://devices.live.com/Sync/Summary, select the folder you want to share, then select "Edit permissions."

Not exactly intuitive, but this should let you share the folder.